# Declare External Functions In A Cocoa / Obj-C Project

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa, function

Ok, here goes. I've completed a Cocoa foundation-tool that calculates mean absolute deviation of random integers (Just as a learning project).

I've moved the calculation into a function called "findMeanAbsoluteDeviation()" It accepts a NSMutableArray of NSNumber objects to preform calculations. Anyways. So this works all fine and dandy when I declare it in the same ".m" file as my other code.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

float findMeanAbsoluteDeviation(NSMutableArray * array);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    ...generate random integers, execute function...
    meanAbsoluteDeviation = findMeanAbsoluteDeviation(numArray);
}

float findMeanAbsoluteDeviation(NSMutableArray * array) {
    ...mean absolute deviation maths...
```

}

and it works fine. Now, I would like to move the function to an external file. I created a 
subclass of NSObject named "mad". I moved the function into my mad "mad.m", I read up and then re-formatted the declaration to look like

```
-(float)findMeanAbsoluteDeviation:(NSMutableArray *)array {
    ...code...
}
```

and in my "mad.h" file.

```
@interface mad : NSObject {

}

    - (float)findMeanAbsoluteDeviation:(NSMutableArray *)array;

@end
```

seems all awesome. Right? all I have to do is add...

```
#import "mad.m"
```

to the top of my "main.m" file and use the function as I would normally. Well, it doesn't seem to compile correctly.

```
ld: duplicate symbol .objc_class_name_mad in ------standardDeviation.build/Debug/standardDeviation.build/Objects-normal/i386/mad.o and ------standardDeviation.build/Debug/standardDeviation.build/Objects-normal/i386/standardDeviation.o
```

"------" is omitted for length's sake

```
Command /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.0 failed with error code 1
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `#import "mad.h"`, not `#import "mad.m"` otherwise the class implementation is evaluated twice, hence the error you're seeing.

A few stylistic points:

- If you're not using an object's instance variables for anything, you typically write a class method (+) not an instance method (-).
- There's no problem declaring a C function prototype in an Objective-C header file, if a class interface doesn't make sense for what you're doing.  See `NSGeometry.h` for some examples.
- If you don't mutate an array in a function or method, don't use a mutable array parameter.
- Consider using standard Cocoa naming conventions for classes, methods and functions.

For example:

```
@interface MEMeanAbsoluteDeviation : NSObject {
}
+ (float)meanAbsoluteDeviation:(NSArray *)array;
```

or simply:

```
float MEMeanAbsoluteDeviation(NSArray *array);
```

Comment: Ok. I'm loving Stack Overflow. Thank you so much. I changed my "#import" statement. 

I then read (http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html) up on class methods, I was wondering what the difference was between + and -. Thank you so much. I am eternally grateful :)

One more question, can if my function accepts an NSArray, can I pass it a NSMutableArray becuase it is a subclass of NSArray, or should I NSAray *copyArray = [NSArray initWithArray: myMutableArray]; ? I'm pretty sure its the former.

Comment: Yes, if a method or function takes an object of a particular class it can take an object of a subclass as well.  If you do need to make a mutable object (array, dictionary, etc.) out of an immutable one or vice versa, the methods to use are "-copy" (mutable => immutable) and "-mutableCopy" (immutable => mutable).